# How to typeset in-Text secondary citation i.e. Example (2005, as cited in Doe, 2010, p.3) in APA style

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I am using biblatex with a biber backend and would like to output an in-text secondary citation that looks like

Example (2005, as cited in Doe, 2010, p.3),

where (Doe, 2010) is in my bibliography.

The parenthetical version of this can be achieved via `\autocite[][]{}` as demonstrated in the following MWE, but I am not sure how to achieve the in-text version of this:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{mybib.bib}
@book{test1,
    address = {City},
    title = {{Generic Title}},
    publisher = {Doe, Jane},
    author = {Doe, Jane},
    year = {2010}
}

\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass[
12pt
]{book} % The class file specifying the document structure

% Set the values for the bibliography
\usepackage[
style=apa,
backend=biber,
isbn=false,
url=true,
doi=true,
natbib=true,
eprint=false,
hyperref=true,
backref=false,
firstinits=false
]{biblatex}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage{xpatch}

% Set language
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}

\addbibresource{mybib.bib}



\addbibresource{mybib.bib}

\begin{document}

\autocite[Example, 2005, as cited in][p. 3]{test1}


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Example 2005 should not appear in your reference list and does not appear in your `.bib` file, you can write the citation in parentheses manually with `\nptextcite`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
  Example \parentext{2005, as cited in \nptextcite[381]{sigfridsson}}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Example (2005, as cited in Sigfridsson & Ryde, 1998, p. 381)]

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly!